A tag for questions where coins are sent to a different cryptocurrency by mistake?
eg when BTC is sent to a Litecoin address, or to a Bitcoin-Gold or Bitcoin-Cash address. These kinds of question are becoming quite common.
We have tags for wallet-recovery and recover-private-key, but nothing that really seems appropriate. Any ideas for an appropriate tag, perhaps something like funds-sent-to-wrong-cryptocurrency ?

How about cross-chain-recovery? If you create it, please add a tag-wiki excerpt to explain it and add it to at least a few likely questions!

Thanks; I've used that tag name

Are there really a lot of different questions that would use this tag? Or just the ones which get closed as duplicates of the few original questions? For example, I've seen a lot of BTC <-> BCH questions which are just duplicates, and therefore closed. Hopefully we aren't going to keep seeing more and more forks, so S2X, BCH, BTG and BTC are hopefully the only pairs which might commonly get confused, and therefore there's only a limited number of original questions of this type possible right?

While the site remains open to altcoins, there are likely to be ongoing issues from other hard forks. Besides, the similar naming of Bitcoin Cash and Bitcoin Gold may mean this is an ongoing problem for Bitcoin too. If most questions were duplicates, I wouldn't bother, but there are a lot of different circumstances that affect a solution.
